# How to limit GAE datastore size to the free quota? So that I won't be charged?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to limit GAE Datastore size to the free quota 1G? So that I won't be charged?

Comment: I think the proper way to limit your costs would be to set a daily budget of 0 cents. That or you should not have entered your credit card information in the first place. Since you're not asking for a programmatic way of achieving your goal (and you show not effort of trying to do so) this question is off-topic and too broad imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Calculate on the go how much you store and once near the limit stop adding records to DB
2. Use GAE stats API to do the same (*it can have a delay up to 24 hours*): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats
3. Simply do not switch on payments - GAE will limit your app automatically once you've hit the quota.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  So there's no way like the MongoDB capped collection, which can limit the size.   I guess I'll just use option 3.

Comment: it *might* be preferable to enable billing but configure a tiny daily budget (some services have higher free quota and some are only available to paid apps) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit

Comment: Hi, you should have be careful with option 3. When your app limit is reached, app engine simply is not going to receive more requests and all requests will be redirected to an error page.